How do I get a *http.Request in a Huma handler?
I'm using the Line (chat app) SDK for Go and it provides a webhook.ParseRequest() function that takes an argument r *http.Request.
I want to use this function in a Huma request handler, but Huma Operations only seem to provide a context.Context object.
How do I get a *http.Request object into the Huma handler so that I can use it when calling webhook.ParseRequest()?



create a custom operation
type CustomOp struct { huma.Operation  Request *http.Request}


middle ware add value to context
ctx := context.WithValue(r.Context(), "http_request", r) next.ServeHTTP(w, r.WithContext(ctx))


use the handler
func WebhookHandler(ctx context.Context, op *CustomOp) error {   req := op.Request   events, err := webhook.ParseRequest(req)}


have you tried this approch ??

@skshahriarahmedraka No, I'm new to Go, if you post an answer with formatted code I'll upvote it, I'm asking ChatGPT for more information now.

it's not about upvote and downvote  brother , check out this code snippet , https://go.dev/play/p/8CPi-zuKePF
